# Python consecutive subprocess calls with adb

Tags: android, python, adb

I am trying to make a python script to check the contents of a database via adb. The thing is that in my code,only the first subprocess.call() is executed and the rest are ignored. Since i am fairly new to Python, i am not sure how to fix it. This is the code:

```
import subprocess

def root():
    subprocess.call('adb shell',shell=True)
    x=input('Enter package name: ')
    openSql(x)


def openSql(x):
    subprocess.call('cd data/data/%s/databases/'%(x),shell=True)
    table=input('Enter table name: ')
    openTable(table)

def openTable(table):
    subprocess.call('sqlite3 table',shell=True)
    subprocess.call('select * from %s'%(table),shell=True)

root()
```

It gives no error but it just enters root at my emulator and nothing else.

```
root@android:/ #
```

Answer (score 1):

You call the `root` function `root()`, which drops you into the adb shell. You are trying to run a `python` command `input` from the adb shell which will not work.

A couple of links to help do what you want:

[runpythonfromshell](http://code.google.com/p/python-for-android/wiki/RunPythonFromShell)

[sl4a](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/wiki/UserGuide)

Comment: Thx for the quick response. I see.  Is there any  way to achieve what i want or it's not possible?

Comment: It is possible alright, why don't you run it all from a python shell?

Comment: You could run the python command from the adb  to start a python shell.

Comment: I am a little bit confused. I open `idle` and i am into the python shell(assuming that's what you meant) and then what? If i run `subprocess.call('adb shell',shell=True)` i can't interact with it anymore until i exit from the `root@android:/#`

Comment: Oh i just saw your edit with the links. I am going to check them for sure. Thx for the info.

Answer (score 0):

```
import subprocess

p=input('Enter package name: ')
d=input('Enter database name: ')
t=input('Enter table name: ')
print subprocess.check_output(["adb", "shell", "sqlite3 /data/data/{}/databases/{}.db 'select * from {};'".format(p, d, t)])
```